# Box-and-circle diagram of a double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Does anyone have a link to a box-and-circle diagram of a double pointer?

Comment: Is that similar/the same as a box-and-pointer diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out

http://www.mattababy.org/~belmonte/Teaching/CCC/CCC/transparent_figure5.gif

from this [crash course in C](http://www.mattababy.org/~belmonte/Teaching/CCC/CrashCourseC.html).  It shows a "pointer to a pointer" diagram in terms of a two-dimensional array.

If you're looking for something more basic:

```
  ______        ____       _____
 /      \      /    \     |     |
| int**  |--->| int* |--->| int |
 \______/      \____/     |_____|
```

Comment: Do you mean &&x, &x, and x?  Or do the ** and * indicate the type (as in when defining (?) a variable)?

Comment: @strager: Yeah, I was thinking type ... d'oh