# Why does this program have unexpected pointer values?

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote this to test my knowledge on pointers:

```
int main (){
  int seven = 7;
  int* p = &seven;
  int** pp = &p;
  int*** ppp = &pp;
  printf("%d %d %d %d\n", *ppp, &pp, &p, &seven);
}
```

However, in the output, I get:

`1363848032 1363848024 1363848032 1363848044`

This is unintuitive to me because `*ppp == &p`

I was expecting `*ppp == &pp`. Why is this happening? Does the `&pp` follow the pointer to `p`?

Comment: always use the `"%p"` format specifier for printing pointer addresses! also, return something from main (as it has to return `int`), to be pedantic return `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `stdlib.h`, and last but not least, eather write `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])`

Comment: Yessir, will do in the future @PeterVaro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to explain the problem with the following schema:

```
  ppp     pp       p    seven      <---- variable names
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+
| 30 |  | 20 |  | 10 |  |  7 |     <---- memory contents
+----+  +----+  +----+  +----+
  40      30      20      10       <---- memory addresses
```

In the above diagram the boxes represent individual memory slots where your variables are stored. The number under each one of those boxes is the address of that place in memory.

Now pointer really only is a variable whose value is a number that happens to be the memory address of some other variable.
So when you say `*ppp` you ask for the value of variable that is at address `30`, which equals to `20`, which is the address of `p`. So you get `*ppp == &p` and `ppp == &pp`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int*** ppp = &pp;
```

So why do you expect `*ppp == &pp`? (note the extra `*` dereference)

Comment: Shouldn't `ppp`'s value be the addr of `pp`? And therefore when dereferencing, `*ppp == (addr of pp)`?

Comment: You shoudn't dereference to get the value of something.... If `ppp` has a value, to get it, you write `ppp`....

Comment: @ylun.ca `ppp == &pp`, so `*ppp == *(&pp)`

Comment: Interesting.... So basically I should think of a pointer as a box that holds the address of the pointer it points to. So therefore when I dereference a pointer it retrieves the value in the box of what the pointer points to?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath So then when I dereference, I'm actually getting the value of pp, which is &p. (Right??)

Comment: @ylun.ca: right. "that holds the address of the *thing* it points to".

Comment: You can draw a box diagram if it's unclear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641156/box-and-circle-diagram-of-a-double-pointer

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
  int seven = 7;
  int* p = &seven;
  int** pp = &p;
  int*** ppp = &pp;

  printf("%d %d \n", *p, seven);
  printf("%d %d \n", **pp, seven);
  printf("%d %d \n", ***ppp, seven);


  printf("%p %p \n", p, &seven);
  printf("%p %p \n", pp, &p);
  printf("%p %p \n", ppp, &pp);
  printf("%p %p \n", *ppp, pp);

}


        $ ./ptr 
        7 7 
        7 7 
        7 7 
       0x7ffe4dce54b4 0x7ffe4dce54b4 
       0x7ffe4dce54a8 0x7ffe4dce54a8 
       0x7ffe4dce54a0 0x7ffe4dce54a0 
       0x7ffe4dce54a8 0x7ffe4dce54a8
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way of looking at this: Boxes and Box numbers. You can put all kinds of numbers into boxes, including box numbers.

In your example:

`7` is put into a box (variable `seven`) which has a box number of `&seven`.

Then you create a new box (variable `p`) to hold `7`'s box number (`&seven`), which in turn has a box number of `&p`.

Later you do the same, and so on.

`ppp` holds `pp`'s box number, which was created to hold `p`'s box number which in turn was created to hold `seven`'s box number.

```
*ppp = pp
*pp  = p
*p   = seven = 7
```